# Mom gifted me property that she inherited what is my cost basis?

Tags: united-states, inheritance

The land was inherited by my mother around 30 years ago and was transfered to my wife and I in 2014 as a gift.She passed away in 2016. I sold the property for 23,500 in 2019. What is my cost basis? do I owe any capital gains  since it was a gift and is less than 14000 gift exemption for me and 14000 for my wife which would make a 28000 total gift exemption?

Comment: Tax questions require jurisdiction to be answerable. Where in the world are you?

Comment: Property was in West Virginia, I live in Idaho.

Comment: Is the title of the land sold in both your names or just one name?

Comment: Both of us were on the deed.

Comment: And you have no property valuation/tax assessment either at or around the time of transfer? Also any improvements to the land (roads, structures) either by your mother or yourself since when it was gifted?